# method prototype style clarification

Tags: c++, methods, prototype

when declaring a method prototypes, is it acceptable style to leave out the parameter name and show only the type, if it's obvious what the parameter is? Example:

```
bool setGender(char);
bool setRomance(int);
bool setName(string);
```

[..]

```
double determineGenderFit(DateProfile);
double determineRomanceFit(DateProfile);
double determineFinanceFit(DateProfile);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's  acceptable to remove parameter names from declaration of functions. Although including names  would be an improvement in self-documentation condition your name reflect actual use of the object.